# Websphere 7: The META-INF/config/ibmaxis2.xml Axis2 global configuration file cannot load correctly

Tags: java, apache, websphere, apache-axis, websphere-7

I'm deploying EAR file on WAS 7, deployment fails and I got this in the :

```
 java.lang.Exception: WSWS7018E: The META-INF/config/ibmaxis2.xml Axis2 global configuration file cannot load correctly because of the following error: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.component.WASAxis2ComponentImpl.loadAxis2ConfigurationContext(WASAxis2ComponentImpl.java:1133)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deployment.WASAxis2MetaDataProcessor.loadConfiguration(WASAxis2MetaDataProcessor.java:471)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deployment.WASAxis2MetaDataProcessor.processModuleMetadata(WASAxis2MetaDataProcessor.java:430)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deployment.WASAxis2MetaDataProcessor.processApplicationMetaData(WASAxis2MetaDataProcessor.java:204)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.component.WASAxis2ComponentImpl.moduleMetaDataCreated(WASAxis2ComponentImpl.java:2228)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.component.WASAxis2ComponentImpl.metaDataCreated(WASAxis2ComponentImpl.java:930)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.fireMetaDataCreated(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebMetaDataFactory.createMetaData(WebMetaDataFactory.java:205)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaDataFromFactories(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:174)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:308)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:605)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:741)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1273)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5305)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5483)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1278)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2050)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:332)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:603)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:565)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1185)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1407)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1303)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1263)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:242)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:353)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:595)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1660)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: WSWS7018E: The META-INF/config/ibmaxis2.xml Axis2 global configuration file cannot load correctly because of the following error: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deployment.WASAxis2ConfigurationBuilder.loadAxisCfg(WASAxis2ConfigurationBuilder.java:520)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deployment.WASAxis2ConfigurationBuilder.loadAxisServerConfiguration(WASAxis2ConfigurationBuilder.java:179)
at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.component.WASAxis2ComponentImpl.loadAxis2ConfigurationContext(WASAxis2ComponentImpl.java:1102)
... 81 more
```

This issue happened after adding maven plugin to my eclipse (although the ear is an old one which is not generated using maven)
And this issue happens with more than one ear.

I have tried to create another profile, but i got the same issue.

Comment: You've either didn't deploy it to WAS before, or had changed something else also. Installing just maven plugin to Eclipse shouldn't have any impact on Ear.

Comment: I have deployed it many times before.
I agree with you , it's not the maven plugin.
but I cannot find the WAS issue cause.
kindly note that this issue happened with other applications , not only this EAR

Comment: Any updates on WAS side like fixpacks? New, different environment? Updates to the application libraries?

Comment: No , I cannot remember anything new , finally I have uninstalled WAS and re-installed it again. coz I have no time for more investigation in this issue. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Investigation,

1- The Ear file is OK. Its old and I can deploy it successfully on another machine.

2- The profile is OK. I found the same issue after creating a new profile.

So, I'm sure that it's an issue in my WAS. But I have no time to investigate the real cause.

As a fast solution, I have installed the WAS and re-installed it. And it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the EAR is build with Maven, the error can be caused by a version of Axis2 that has been downloaded with Maven. Try to exclude it from your pom and only use the version provided by the WebSphere JRE.

But if you say that the EAR is not build with Maven... There is no reason that WebSphere has another behaviour. It is independent of the Eclipse plugins.

Comment: The Ear is not built by Maven.
It's a WAS issue, not maven dependancies